# When is a Hausdorff space metrisable?

Tags: gn.general-topology

This question may be a little too easy for this site, but I'll ask it anyway: when is a Hausdorff topological space metrisable?

Comment: I think this site is a little too hung up about avoiding easy questions.  I understand they don't want the site to degrade into a homework Q&A, but I think questions like yours are fine.  

Comment: One word.. "Nagata"

Answer (score 7):

The wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrisability) is probably of interest. It contains links to a few metrization theorems, including results of [Nagata-Smirnov's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata-Smirnov_metrization_theorem) and [Bing's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_metrization_theorem). There is also the Smirnov metrization theorem that appears in Munkres' topology: it states that A space X is metrizable if and only if it is paracompact, Hausdorff, and locally metrizable.

Comment: This Wikipedia page is an excellent answer to the question.  Urysohn's theorem (second-countable, regular, Hausdorff is metrizable) and Smirnov's theorem (locally metrizable, Hausdorff, paracompact is metrizable) really are what people use all the time.


Answer (score 3):

I think it's also worth pointing out the Wikipedia page on [Moore spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_%28topology%29).  It turns out that the *full* answer to your question (if you don't allow conditions like "locally metrizable") has something to do with the Continuum Hypothesis.

Comment: Whatever is a "full" answer? Isn't the "full" answer "A top space is metrisable iff there exists a metric inducing the topology"? What did you have in mind Henry? Probably not that!

Comment: Fair point.  I suppose by *a* full answer I meant an equivalent condition to metrisability that doesn't use the notion of metrisability anywhere (eg in locally metrisable).  I *think* that the condition provided by Jones' Theorem is necessary and sufficient (subject to some assumption about the Continuum Hypothesis).